# How to extract strings from column into a new column?

Tags: regex, google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I am new to google sheets.

How do I loop over column `C` and extract every occurence of `Dog` and `Mouse` together with its "index" `A, C, D` into columns `E` and `F`?

[image]

The best thing I can do right now is extract the strings row by row with

`=IFS($C:$C="Dog"; $B:$B;$C:$C="Mouse";$B:$B;1=1; "")` and
`=IFS($C:$C="Dog"; $C:$C;$C:$C="Mouse";$C:$C;1=1; "")`

but this leaves free spaces in the new columns:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this works

```
=filter(B3:C, regexmatch(C3:C, "Dog|Mouse"))
```

or, depending on your locale

```
=filter(B3:C; regexmatch(C3:C; "Dog|Mouse"))
```

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0):

If all you are looking for is a simple extract you could do the following:

```
=QUERY(B:C,"SELECT B,C WHERE C = 'Dog' OR C = 'Mouse'")
```

OR

```
=QUERY(B:C;"SELECT B,C WHERE C = 'Dog' OR C = 'Mouse'")
```

[image]

If you want to add more to add another output just add another `OR C = 'TEXT'` to the formula.

QUERY function: [Link](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en#)

Comment: I believe the second semi-colon (second formula) should be a comma.

Comment: Not used to the (second formula) semi-colon style. Made an assumtion all commas would be swapped out for semi-colons. Cheers for the heads up.

Answer (score 0):

try simple:

```
=QUERY(B:C; "where C matches 'Dog|Mouse'"; 0)
```

note regex is case sensitive so if you need you can do:

```
=QUERY(B:C; "where lower(C) matches 'dog|mouse'"; 0)
```